# Ways to control multiple linear actuators seperately?

Tags: microcontroller, linear, actuator

I intend to control multiple linear actuators at the same time (20+). These actuators need ~9V each to run, and I simply want them to either be on (pulling) or off (relaxed). Each actuator is to be controlled seperately

My current solution to the problem is to use a microcontroller with multiple outputs, and to hook up each output to an N channel mosfet, with each mosfet having its sources connected to a 9V source.

I am curious though, would there be another way to control these actuators without the need of so many mosfets?

Comment: what current do the actuators need?

Comment: You could use ULN2803A to driver 8 of these actuators. The chip can sink a total of 2.5A so providing that all of them are on at a time you're looking at max 300mA each.

Comment: If you need independent unidirectional control, typically you would use an N-channel MOSFET as a low side switch for each.  However, you might also consider a matrix arrangement if you only need to activate a small fraction of them at any given time, or if you can activate them with a reduced duty cycle (and perhaps higher drive while active).  Flyback diodes in the matrix case may need a little thought.

Comment: Please post a link to the actuator and datasheet you plan to use. Do they have enough friction, or a holding mechanism, sufficient to keep them in place without powering them? Usually, driving them as you describe, with a single N-MOSFET would only drive them in one direction. Is that all you need to do? If you need to drive them in both directions, then the drive circuit will be even more complex.